# How to transfer a grid drawing to a canvas resource for download using front-end JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend, html5-canvas

How can front-end JavaScript be used to Download a Client-side drawing?

I am working on an etch-a-sketch project, which uses CSS grid to provide the drawing board and creates a "drawing" effect by manipulating the background-color of each grid element that is clicked. You can view it on Codepen here: https://codepen.io/black-ram/pen/dyggLNJ

As a final feature, I wanted to add the ability to download the "sketch", and this is the code I used:

```
// To Download
function downloadDrawing() {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Set the canvas size to match the grid dimensions
  const grid = document.getElementById('grid-container');
  const width = grid.offsetWidth;
  const height = grid.offsetHeight;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  // Draw each grid element onto the canvas
  const gridElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.grid-element')];
  gridElements.forEach((element) => {
    const { top, left, width, height, backgroundColor } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    context.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
    context.fillRect(left, top, width, height);
  });

  // Generate data URL for the canvas content
  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

  // Create a download link
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = dataURL;
  link.download = 'drawing.png';
  link.click();
}

// Attach the downloadDrawing function to a button
document.getElementById('download-button').addEventListener('click', downloadDrawing);
```

However, the actual downloaded image invariably looks like:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7MS2.png)

I'm very unfamiliar with using canvas and downloading, so help would be greatly appreciated in troubleshooting.